# ¿Como accedo a una propiedad especifica de un foreach (.map, .each)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy intentado que los `console.log` traigan los id del `select` y `input number` dependiendo sobre cual se ejecute la acción `keyup`, si escribo sobre el input con `id="resultado_uno"`, que me traiga los id `resultado_uno` y `select_uno`, si escribo sobre el input con `id="resultado_dos"`, que me traiga los id `resultado_dos` y `select_dos`, yo se que solo trae los "`_dos`" por que esa es la función del `map`, recorrer datos, y obviamente me va a traer el ultimo dato pero, ¿No ay manera de hacer lo que quiero? De antemano, muchas gracias!

EJEMPLO DE LO QUE TENGO:

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.unResultado', function() {
  $('#todosInputs').find(":input").map(function() {
    if ($(this).is(".unResultado")) {
      resultadoId = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
    }
    if ($(this).is(".unSelect")) {
      selectId = "#" + $(this).attr('id');
    }
  });
  console.log(selectId+" / "+resultadoId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="todosInputs">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Deemo 1</label>
            <select class="form-control select2 unSelect" id="select_uno">
                <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                <option value="1">Uno</option>
                <option value="2">Dos</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Deemo 2</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control unResultado" id="resultado_uno" value="" step="any">
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>Deemo 1</label>
                <select class="form-control select2 unSelect" id="select_dos">
                    <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                    <option value="1">Uno</option>
                    <option value="2">Dos</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>Deemo 2</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control unResultado" id="resultado_dos" value="" step="any">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

para recorrer los elementos hijos dentro de un elemento padre usa el metodo de jquery each()

```
$('.elemento_padre_que_se_quiere_recorrer input').each(function(index) {
  // con this apuntas al elemento (objeto) que se esta actualmente recorriendo
  var este_hijo = $(this)  //con 

  // para sacar el id seria asi
  var id_este_hijo = este_hijo.attr('id')
})
```

Así en la function() que es uno de los parámetros de each() colocas todo el código que quieres hacer sobre el $(this) elemento actual

el apuntador de each() son los elementos que quieres recorrer